# Sement by tag Onesignal

Tags: php, push-notification, tags, onesignal

I try send push notifications only to users segmented by tags from my app with Onesignal by php but the notificatión is send to all users, this is my code:

```
    $fields = array(
        'app_id'            => $onesignal_wp_settings['app_id'],
        'headings'          => array("en" => get_the_title($post->ID), "es" => get_the_title($post->ID)),
        'isAnyWeb'          => false,
        'url'               => get_permalink($post->ID),
        'contents'          => array("es" => max_words(array(
                                  "max" => 40,
                                  "id_post" => $post -> ID
                              )),
                                "es" => max_words(array(
                                  "max" => 40,
                                  "id_post" => $post -> ID
                              ))),
        'tags' => array(
            array(
                "key" => "municipio",
                "relation" => "=",
                "value" => (string)$id_municipio
            ),
            array(
                "operator" => "OR"
            ),
            array(
                "key" => "estado",
                "relation" => "=",
                "value" => (string)$id_estado
            )
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

The `contents` field of your code isn't correct. It can only contain an array of languages with a string for it's contents. Your `post_id` should be added to `data` instead.

```
'contents' => array("en" => "English message",
                    "es" => "Spanish message"),
'data' => array("id_post" => $post -> ID)
```

Your `tags` field looks correct however I am not sure what your variables contain. You should print out your full JSON payload to make sure you don't have any errors in the format.